# PyQGIS CRS projection issue when converting shapefile to heatmap

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis, shapefile, heat-map

I am trying to create a Python script that runs in the QGIS Python Console and uses the QGS API to create KDE heatmaps from shapefiles. The shapefiles can come in any number of CRS's but the heatmaps must all be created in EPSG: 6350

I am using a shapefile of points of chemical sampling sites and trying to create a heatmap of those points.

This is my first project in PyQGIS and I am having some trouble with the CRS projection of the heatmap.

When I do this process manually I have to export the shapefile in espg: 6350 then reimport it to create the heatmap. I have tried to do this in pyqgis but it is still projecting the heatmap incorrectly.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import processing
import os

#set project crs
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
selectedcrs="EPSG:6350"
target_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
target_crs.createFromUserInput(selectedcrs)
canvas.setDestinationCrs(target_crs)

sites = "/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/SHAPEFILES/NH_PFAS/PFAS_20200603_jwa_noneg_shp.shp"

vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(sites, "sites layer", "ogr")
if not vlayer:
  print("Layer failed to load!")
  
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

#set layer crs
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:6350'))

str = "/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/SHAPEFILES/NH_PFAS_epsg_6350/PFAS_epsg_6350.shp"

#export the layer with the new crs
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,str,'utf-8',driverName='ESRI Shapefile')


#process it using chemical value as the weighing factor
processing.run("qgis:heatmapkerneldensityestimation", {'INPUT':'/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/SHAPEFILES/gwTCE_NH/PFAS_epsg_6350.shp|\
layername=PFAS_epsg_6350','RADIUS':1600,'RADIUS_FIELD':'','PIXEL_SIZE':100,'WEIGHT_FIELD':'Total PFAS',\
'KERNEL':0,'DECAY':0,'OUTPUT_VALUE':0,\
'OUTPUT':'/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/HEATMAPS/Heat1.tif'})

#add the heatmap for viewing
path_to_tif = "/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/HEATMAPS/Heat1.tif"

iface.addRasterLayer(path_to_tif, "Heat1")
```

Any suggestions as to why I am not getting the correct projection of the heatmap or other suggestions to improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest running the 'Reproject Layer' algorithm on your input layer and pass the output layer as input to the heatmap algorithm. You can store the reprojection output in a temporary memory layer to reduce the need for multiple saved versions of shapefiles. Also, if you are just running this script in the Python console you don't need all those imports. Try the code snippet below and see if this works satisfactorily.

```py
sites = '/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/SHAPEFILES/NH_PFAS/PFAS_20200603_jwa_noneg_shp.shp'

#construct a QgsVectorLayer object
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(sites, 'sites_layer', 'ogr')

# load input layer if desired (comment out this line if not required)
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)

#reproject input layer to epsg: 6350
r = processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':layer,
'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:6350'),
'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

#define path to output tif
output_path = '/Users/justinandrew/Documents/Personal/geospatial_fall_2020/qgis_projects/shapefile_to_hmap_pyqgis_dev_2020_11_13/HEATMAPS/Heat1.tif'

#process it using chemical value as the weighing factor
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:heatmapkerneldensityestimation", {'INPUT':r['OUTPUT'],
'RADIUS':1600,
'RADIUS_FIELD':'',
'PIXEL_SIZE':100,
'WEIGHT_FIELD':'Total PFAS',
'KERNEL':0,'DECAY':0,'OUTPUT_VALUE':0,
'OUTPUT':output_path})
```

Also, here is a great tip for running processing algorithms from the Python console to ensure you use the correct syntax for all parameters etc. Run the algorithm via the gui first then click on the history icon:

[image]

Then select a previously run algorithm to see the associated Python call:

[image]